# Not able to access public variable outside class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

For the given class I can not access the public variable outside class.I want to access variable payload and `$_GLOBALS['te']` outside the class but it is giving `NULL` value.

It should show value of payload outside of class when I print payload variable inside `show_data()` it is returning the correct value.

```
<?php

class google_api
{
    public $test;
    public $payload;
    public $id_token;


    function add_platform_script()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('platform_scr', 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:platform.js', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('handler_callback', plugins_url('../js/google_sign.js', __FILE__), false);
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array ($this, 'add_platform_script'), 1);
        wp_localize_script('handler_callback', 'show_vfr', array ('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    }

    public function add_api_js()
    {
        $this->add_platform_script();
        echo
        '<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY CLIENT ID"><div class="g-signin2"
                                                                  data-scope="profile email"
                                                                  data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
                                                                  data-onfailure="onSignInFailure"> </div>';
        $GLOBALS['te'] = 'helloee';
    }

    function show_data($client)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['Token'])) {
            $this->id_token = $_POST['Token'];
            $CLIENT_ID      = 'MY CLIENT ID';
            $client         = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);

            $this->payload = $client->verifyIdToken($this->id_token);
            if ($this->payload) {
                $user_email = $this->payload['email'];
                if (email_exists($user_email)) {
                    $user = get_user_by('email', $user_email);
                    if ($user) {
                        wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
                        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
                        do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);
                        die('1');
                    }
                } else {
                    die('2');
                }
            } else {
                echo 'INVALID TOKEN ISSUED [ERR 005]'; // Invalid ID token
            }
        } else {
            echo 'INVALID USER';
        }
    }

}

$foo = new google_api();
add_action('google_button_form', array ($foo, 'add_api_js'));
var_dump($foo->payload);
var_dump($GLOBALS['te']);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_show_data', array ($foo, 'show_data'));
```

Comment: You have `payload` or `test` properties, but not `paytest`

Comment: yeah i have corrected paytest to payload, it was a typo while typing the question. Even with $foo->payload i am not able to access the variable it always return NULL @u_mulder

Comment: You understand that `add_action` just adds a function, but doesn't execute it?

Comment: Yes! the show_data() function is invoked by external js file which it localized to admin-ajax.php and as soon ajax method in js is executed 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_data' hook is triggered in add_action. @u_mulder

Comment: $foo->payload won't have a value until `$foo->show_data()` is called. Even if it is eventually called from an external js file, it won't have a value before it is actually called.

Comment: Ohh thank you!!! @amenadiel but if i call `$foo->show_data()`  the `$_POST['Token'] ` will be empty and code won't work. any suggestion for my code ?

Comment: just avoid calling var_dump until show_data is actually called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about how filters work, and when your code is actually executed.

Your property `payload` wont be set until the method `show_data` runs, and that wont happen until the action `wp_ajax_nopriv_show_data` is triggered. (By accessing the proper ajax URL).

Since the object will exist only during that request, your `payload` property will be only accessible inside that same method.